# How do I rotate a Texture2D twice?

Tags: c#, rotation, xna, texture2d

I have a Texture2D in C# and XNA. I need to rotate it once around one point and then again around another. If I use the following code as an example, it draws the texture twice.

```
Texture2D texture;
float rotation = (float)Math.PI;
Vector2 originOne = new Vector2();
Vector2 originTwo = new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2);

spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(300, 200, 100, 100), null, Color.White, rotation, originOne, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(300, 200, 100, 100), null, Color.White, rotation, originTwo, SpriteEffects.None, 0.0f);
```

Is there any way for me to draw the texture once after rotating it around two different points? Is there any way for me to merge the two rotations into one calculation?

Comment: I haven't used XNA, but generally you can do this by multiplying transformation matrices together. The process for a single rotation around a point is: (1) translate to move the rotation pivot to `0,0` (2) rotate the object (3) do the opposite of the earlier translation. So you'd do that process once for each rotation you want to do.

Comment: I guess you either need to use a custom shader to do the translation/rotation, or use a different render target first and then rotate the result again.